# How to post image in twitter using Twitterizer?

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter

I have a requirement to  tweet an image to twitter. I am using Twitterizer and almost I followed every step to do. I tweeted the text also. But when I try to tweet an image I am getting a response as unknown and the tweet is not happening.

```
StatusUpdateOptions opts = new StatusUpdateOptions();
byte[] photo = File.ReadAllBytes(Request.MapPath("~/img/SPxx.png"));
TwitterResponse<TwitterStatus> response = TwitterStatus.UpdateWithMedia(accesstoken, "Testing Image Tweet", photo, opts);
```

Any idea what I am missing.

This is the code I am using.

Thanks